# why is php class class giving me error when trying to access the class

Tags: php, html, css

this is the error I get.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION
>   in /home/students/000313753/public_html/10065/php/lab2/lab2.php on
>   line 121

my class

```
        class validate
        {
            public $errorArray;



                function userName($name)
                {
                    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
                    {
                        if(isset($name))
                        {
                            if(strlen($name) <= 5)
                            {
                                $this->$errorArray['name'] = 'The username must be 5 characters.';  
                            }   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->$errorArray['name'] = 'Username cannot be empty';
                        }

                    }
                }
                function validateEmail($email)
                {
                    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
                    {
                        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
                        {
                            $this->$errorArray['email'] = 'Wrong email format.';
                        }
                    }
                }

                function validateYear($year)
                {
                    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
                    {
                        if (isset($year))
                        {
                            if ($year < 1000 || $year > 2100)
                            {
                                $this->$errorArray['year'] = 'Year must be a 4 digit number.';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->$errorArray['year'] = 'Year cannot be empty';
                        }
                    }

                function validateProvinces($provinces)
                {
                    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
                    {
                        if (isset($provinces))
                        {
                            if (empty($provinces))
                            {
                                $this->$errorArray['provinces'] = 'Please select one or more provinces';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                function validateStatus($status)
                {
                    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
                    {
                        if (isset($status))
                        {
                            if (empty($status))
                            {
                                $this->$errorArray['status'] = 'Please select one or more items from status';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }



        }
        //access class
        $validation = new validate()

        $validation->userName($_POST["name"]);
        $validation->validateYear($_POST["year"]);
        $validation->validateProvinces($_POST["provinces"]);
        $validation->validateStatus($_POST["status"]);
        $validation->validateEmail($_POST["email"]);




    ?>
```

I am a beginner and I have over a day trying to debug. Please do not just fix my code provide me with an explanation of why my code do not work.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: $validation = new validate() when i try to use the class.

Comment: Two things - the line '$validation = new validate()' doesn't end with a semicolon. The second thing is I don't see any definition of the class (like "class Validate").

Comment: I did the definition of the class on the top eg. class validate  is this the proper way to do it or not?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing semi-colon here:

```
$validation = new validate()
```

Should be:

```
$validation = new validate();
```

Comment: the semi-colon did not work. Thank you anyway

Comment: More importantly, you are missing the `}` to close `function validateYear`.

Comment: The semi-colon issue was throwing that error and @NiettheDarkAbsol has found you another one.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing closing brace  `}`  in  `function validateYear()`

Comment: Still not working error    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/students/000313753/public_html/10065/php/lab2/lab2.php on line 119

Comment: I have tested, it's working. I think some other problem

Comment: what's the code on line no 119, can you show me that?

Comment: in line 119 I have $validation = new validate() I corrected the brace in validateYear() still not working.

Comment: have you add semi-colon at last as told by Shomz